# How to make Jest recognize JavaScript import map

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, import-maps

I'm trying to setup Jest in my vanilla JavaScript/Express/MongoDB app, but Jest is not recognizing a **JavaScript import map** in a file I am trying to import into my test file(cube.test.cjs). The import map consists of the "OrbitControls.js" file(part of the THREE.js library) which I am loading from a URL when my JavaScript file runs.

cube.test.cjs

```
const fs = await import('fs');
window.document.body.innerHTML = fs.readFileSync("./views/layouts/main.hbs")
import * as Cube from "./cube.js"
.
.
.
```

cube.js

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import * as Index from "./index.js";
.
.
.
```

index.js

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import * as Cube from "./cube.js";
import * as Stopwatch from "./stopwatch.js";
import { WebGL } from "./WebGL.js";
import { OrbitControls } from "orbitcontrols";
.
.
.
```

Here is the import map in main.hbs:

```
    <script type="importmap">
      { 
        "imports": { 
          "three": "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js",
          "orbitcontrols": "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js" 
        } 
      }
    </script>
```

I receive the following error when I run npm test, which triggers Jest.

[image]

Comment: Hey! I'm having a similar issue. Did you find a fix? Thanks

Comment: @carljwood I wasn't able to find a solution for this, but I would try downloading the orbitcontrols package without an import map. See the "Addons" section in the page below. 

Jest may like that better.

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation